# How can I check for some numbers at the end of a string, and increment them by 1 if they exist?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, concatenation

This is an extremely specific scenario, but I'm messing up the syntax here and I'm having trouble researching an optimal/functional way to do it. I'll explain: Let's say I have a string formatted in the following ways: "My-Test-docID", "My-Test-docID-01", "My-Test-docID-02", "My-Test-docID-03", etc.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to first check if the string ends with "-[2 digit number]" or not. If numbers exist at the end, they will always be after a hyphen followed by 2 digits such as "-01", "-02", "-10", etc.

**Example:** If the string is "My-Test-docID" then I would want to change it to "My-Test-docID-01".

If the string DOES end in numbers, then I want to increment them by 1.

**Example:** If the string ends in "-01", I want to change it to "-02" so that "My-Test-docID-01" becomes "My-Test-docID-02". If it ends in "-02" it becomes "-03" such that "My-Test-docID-02" becomes "My-Test-docID-03", etc.

I have some pseudo code ideas, but can't figure out the exact syntax. My intuition tells me to first check for the ending with a regex, then if the number exists, determine what the last two numbers are and increment by 1. What I'm about to write out is certainly not optimal, but it's to show what I've been able to think up so far and hopefully communicate the scenario more clearly.

```
if (docId.endsWith("-[0-9][0-9]")) {
  //last 2 digits of docId +=1
else {
  docId = docId + "-01"
}
```

I have a feeling this will end up looking a lot more complicated, but this is essentially what I'm trying to do, and I'm looking for the proper syntax for the if condition and the if statement.

Note: If it's easier, the number at the end does not have to include the zero in circumstances less than 10 like "-01" and "-02", but I think that might be easier structurally. Realistically they will never be greater than 09, BUT it's not guaranteed and I would like to write this code as dynamic as I can. That being said, greater than "-99" is not really even possible, so I'm not worried about that.

Comment: If string is `My-Test-docID-99` then what it should become?

Comment: That's a good question. I noted that it's really not possible for that to happen, but it does feel bad to leave a gap. I think just leave it as -99. Realistically it wouldn't exceed even 10, but it's potentially possible to go a few over 10 in edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this snippet in Java:

```
String str = "Test-docID-02";
final String regex = "^(.*-)(\\d{2})$";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.matches()) {
    str = m.group(1) + String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)) + 1);
} else {
    str += "-01";
}

//=> Test-docID-03
```

**Regex Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(.*-)`: Match 0 or more characters till last hyphen and capture in group #1
- `(\\d{2})`: Match last 2 digits and capture in group #2
- `$`: End

Note that it will convert `My-Test-docID-99` to `My-Test-docID-100`

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to try and implement this now and test it. I'm curious though, how does this work for the circumstance where ```My-Test-docID``` becomes ```My-Test-docID-01```?

Comment: It seems that this doesn't cover the base case where ```My-Test-docID``` becomes ```My-Test-docID-01```, but this should be something I can easily accomplish with an else condition. I will confirm after testing.

Comment: Adding the else statement worked. Thanks again for the help!